# Iframe Window button that expands to cover another button. How do I pass the unused clicks below?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe button that when click drops down and gives you several options to select.  This button when expanded covers another button.  I need for the iframe to "pass" the unused clicks to the button underneath the iframe window when collapsed.  I know I could just do an onclickevent that changes the z-index.  However, I heard that there is a way to pass unused clicks.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

I created this little js fiddle to demo the issue I am having...  of course, the z-index are already defined in drupal  (for example it overlaps the administration configuration tabs).

http://jsfiddle.net/7a6mLyt4/

```
<div id="test">
<iframe id="timeWidget" src="http://ntws.isti.com/times.php" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Change Time Zone" style="border: 0px solid white; width: 106px; height: 116px; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0">Click to Change Time Zone</iframe>
```

Click Me

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can apply the necessary javascript to the iframe. If you have access to the iframe'd page, you can apply javascript there so that when a certain button is pressed, it also produced the results of the covered button. If the covered button is on a different page than the iframe, you'd have to send the information to a server side code, do the actions there, and send it back to the user if necessary. There is not way to coordinate both pages without server side code.

Your question was rather vague, so if this doesn't answer your question, please edit and expand on it and I will edit my answer and try again.

Comment: Okay, let me try this again.  The iframe has a button inside that has several options when you click it.  Normally, lets say the button is 100px by 20px. but when clicked the options make it 100px by 100px.  However, the iframe is treated as if its 100 by 100 all the time.  This unforunately covers up another button and makes it such that I cannot click anything below the collapsed button.  I'm trying to figure out the cleanest method of having it so the collapsed iframe button passes clicks to the buttons below it on a separate page.

Comment: Ah I see. If you insist on using iframe, you'll need to post a lot of the iframe'd windows html and css and javascript, and even then I probably won't be clever enough to find an answer. It might be worth trying an alternative to iframe and see if they don't have the same problem, but iframe is the best, and any alternatives would likely just create additional problems. Is iframe necessary for this? It's problematic and bad practice. It might even be faster overall to start over without depending on iframe. Can you go without it?

Comment: From a work flow point of view we have a break point where dynamic content is handled by the other developer that is creating a series of widgets.  This widget in particular changes the time zone and utc (which impacts a series of other widget lists).  From a design perspective it makes sense where the button is located...  I'm trying to not spend to much time designing the button and was hoping there was a sort of hacky work around.  As I'm building the website and our buttons are overlapping...  Let me see if I can put together a code example.

Comment: I added a js fiddle example to try and demonstrate the issue I'm having.

Comment: No if you notice you can't click the second button.